# How to give different return values for a mocked function in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Here is the function to test:

```
def func_to_be_tested():
    output_first = func1()
    output_second = func1()
    .... rest of function

# func1 will be mocked while testing func_to_be_tested
```

I want `output_first` and `output_second` to be different, i.e while mocking they should have different return values of `func1` in the same test call for the function `func_to_be_tested`.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) is for. You can assign a list to `side_effect`, and each value in the list will be used as result in subsequent calls, e.g.:

```
from unittest import mock
from path_to_module import func_to_be_tested

@mock.patch('path_to_module.func1')
def test_func_to_be_tested(mocked_func1):
    mocked_func1.side_effect = [output_first, output_second]
    func_to_be_tested()
```

In this case `func1` will return `output_first` in the first call, and `output_second` in the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mrbean Bremen!

Answer (score 0):

Try defining function in a way that either it generates random values or a value dependent on function parameters.